# Firebase Registration Token received but Notification not shown

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an iOS app that should be prepared to receive and show Cloud Messaging Notifications.

This is my AppDelegate class code:

```
import UIKit
import GooglePlaces
import Braintree
import Firebase
import Messages
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift





@UIApplicationMain
 class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

let gcmMessageIDKey = "gmc.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        
        
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
        
        GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("..")
        
        BTAppSwitch.setReturnURLScheme("...")
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

          let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
          let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
          UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
          application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
           if url.scheme?.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare("faro.red.Jogua.payments") == .orderedSame {
               return BTAppSwitch.handleOpen(url, options: options)
           }
           return false
       }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
      // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
      // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
      // TODO: Handle data of notification

      // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
      // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

      // Print message ID.
      if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
      }

      // Print full message.
      print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
      // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
      // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
      // TODO: Handle data of notification

      // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
      // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

      // Print message ID.
      if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
      }

      // Print full message.
      print(userInfo)

      completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }

}
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

  // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              willPresent notification: UNNotification,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([[.alert, .sound, .badge]])
  }

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler()
  }
}
extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
      print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

      let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
      NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
      // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
      // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }
}
```

I am getting the Firebase Registration Token, as shown in the debugger:

```
Firebase registration token: dPyG4q2scEFQhsObtyfdUx:APA91bE9O5MmMiJ2f7...
```

But after sending a notification from Firebase Console, I don't get it in my real device.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have also seen this, it seems that is is related to adding a certificate to the APN for FCM under apple's certs https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs basically I can't figure it out - it's obvious the entire "guide" from google does not match anything whatsoever what is actually on the apple https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action it seems "push notifications" is no longer a tick box but a invitation to add two certificates.. trouble is I have done this and my push notifications still do not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have figured it out .. it is related to the expiry of a provisioning profile or at least it was in my case..

in xcode, open your project, then go to the blue APP_NAME in the top left of your `project navigator`, then choose the correct TARGET in the inner new left hand nav that appeared. it will show you a very white config screen with a hard to recognise series of "tabs" (blue text going blue on select) named:

### General / Signing & Capabilities / Resource Tags / Info / Build Settings / Build Phases

choose `Signing & Capabilities`

the select "all" in the second set of rather hard to detect tabs (an inner list of small black words on white background, blue text for selected names named: "All" "Debug" "Release" you want "ALL")

the untick "automatically manage signing" under "Signing" (a rather hard to detect twister) it should then (`INCREDIBLY` in my mind) "awake" to discover "an issue" a red message that something is not right (mine did), it was an "expiry" on the "push certificate" which I am fairly sure did not exist last time I did this) I just re-selected all the defaults then you can click "some button" (I forget the name but the button appears there and then mid page, next to the red, and if you click it it spins itself away) and voila apple automatically updated it. Once the red goes away, then you can reclick "automatically manage signing" and the error was gone for me

**BEAR IN MIND BEFORE I DID THIS** I did in fact ensure I had created 2 push notification certificates using `Appliances\Keychain` on my macbook then, saving to local drive, uploading them  to https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action following this click train:

- "iOS, tvOS, watchOS" if you need to
- Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles.
- Pick "Identifiers" in list
- chose your project
- scroll to PUSH NOTIFICATIONS near bottom
- click configure (or create) I think it's the only button anyway, mine now says "edit"
- Create "Development SSL Certificate" and "Production SSL Certificate" (I did both)
- upload the certificate you made with `Appliances\Keychain`

I am not sure if this will help you but it fixed it for me

**oh one more thing to bear in mind**

make sure you go to https://console.firebase.google.com/ and follow this click train:

- "Your Firebase projects"
- (choose yours)
- (very top left) "Project Overview" (cog) "Project Settings"
- (choose) "Cloud Messaging" tab
- (scroll down to) "iOS app configuration"
- under "APNs Certificates" make sure your APN certificates are not expired